# Create Tasks on case based on time elapsed after creating case

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I need to create task based on certain rules. For example:

Rule -1) Check case after 24 hours of its creation and if the custom field on case "new status" is blank, create a task with subject "Case not answered"
Rule -2) If the text in custom field is "Ready" after 4 days, 7 days, 10 days, create another task with some subject
and so on

I tried to achieve this using entitlements but cannot get it working and now looking to go with a mix of programmatic and declarative approach if possible. Declarative to define rules and code to implement them.

I am still yet to begin this task. But if anyone experienced this before and can share a better approach, it will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating two (or more) Time-Based Workflow Tasks? The first one would fire as long as the New Status remains blank, but if it was changed, the time-based action would be removed from the time-based workflow queue. Same goes for the 2nd (and subsequent) Rule. This works because queued actions are re-evaluated when the record changes:

> Time-dependent actions remain in the workflow queue only as long as
>   the workflow rule criteria are still valid. If a record no longer
>   matches the rule criteria, Salesforce removes the time-dependent
>   actions queued for that record.
>
> For example, an opportunity workflow
>   rule may specify: A criteria set to “Opportunity: Status not equals to
>   Closed Won, Closed Lost.” An associated time-dependent action with a
>   time trigger set to seven days before the opportunity close date.
>
> If a
>   record that matches the criteria is created on July 1st and the Close
>   Date is set to July 30th, the time-dependent action is scheduled for
>   July 23rd. However, if the opportunity is set to “Closed Won” or
>   “Closed Lost” before July 23rd, the time-dependent action is
>   automatically removed from the queue.

Comment: Thanks AT.. I am trying this approach and will let you know how this worked out. Thanks

Comment: I just realized that I cannot use this approach though this is one of the best solution I feel. Reason for me not using this approach is because there can be a max of 50 (not sure) workflows per object. I can have more than 30 rules and there are Already 10 workflows on case. Please let me know if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @pmvsdt - max # workflows is changeable with a call to Support